# No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' - WCF

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, wcf

I am following the tutoriel [here](http://blog.netapsys.fr/tutoriel-wcf-partie-2/) (in french) but I have this commun error coming when I am testing my WCF application with WcfTestClient.

> No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with
>   invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is
>   registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config
>   file.

I have one Library project for Entity Framework and one project for the WcfSelfHosting.

The error is coming here:

```
public IEnumerable<student> GetAllStudentsOfCourseFinance()
{
  return SchoolDataEntities.enrollements.Where(t => t.course.title == "Finance").Select(t => t.student);
}
```

My App.config in the Library

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

My App.config in WcfSelfHosting project

```
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="schooldataEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Model.csdl|res://*/Data.Model.ssdl|res://*/Data.Model.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=password;database=schooldata&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicTextBinding" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8">
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFExampleLibrary.WCFServices.SchoolWCFService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicTextBinding" contract="WCFExampleLibrary.WCFServices.ISchoolWCFService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/WCFExampleLibrary.WCFServices/SchoolWCFService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I added the Entityframework and  MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6 references in the WcfSelfHosting project.

Comment: i think you've not installed the Mysql libraries for EF? could it be?

Comment: yes I did, MySQL.Data, MySQL.Data.Entity.EF6 and MySQL.Web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose if you use entity framework you must have an ApplicationContext class inheriting from DbContext.If this is the case you need to add an annotation on the ApplicationContext class like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public abstract class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
     //Instructions.........
}
```

You can also edit your Web.Config file at the entityframework tag like this :

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
```

You can always refer to this link :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Comment: I have already tried that. And when I add the entityframework tag, I have this error when I am lauching the service "The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception." "Configuration system failed to initialize"

Comment: It worked when I added the [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))],  Thank you!!