# No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. while generating views

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am getting the following error while generating views for my EF6 project,I looked at other stackoverflow posts related to similar error and updated my app.config accordingly ,I added the `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6` as provider and also added a reference for my EF project,am completely lost as to what my issue is?can anyone provide info on what the issue is or how to debug this?

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
BitDatabaseModel.edmx(7,8) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.ThrowOnNonWarningErrors()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerInvariantName, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider></providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BitDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BitDatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/BitDatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/BitDatabaseModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=xx.xx.xxx.xxx;user id=username;password=passwordname;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=aci_dev&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /></DbProviderFactories>
</system.data></configuration>
```

Project References;

[image]

Comment: One data point is am using `MySQL Connector Net 6.9.9`

Comment: Are there really no other questions here that answer this? I see this question pop up frequently.

Comment: Get Arnold - As I mentioned,I looked at other posts and covered everything mentioned in their posts,so not sure what am I missing?do you have any pointers?

Comment: "Everything". Does that include this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/41544592/861716

Answer (score 1):

This was solved after adding following to web.config

```
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
```