# Exception while loading MySql assemblies

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I followed the steps @https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html to setup EF with MYSQL database for my project but am I running into below error,not sure why?I doublechecked all the steps and I also have a reference to `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 assembly` for my EF project,can anyone provide pointers on what the issue is?

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

```
Additional information: The Entity Framework provider type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information
```

App.config

```
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <!--defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"-->
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>

    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Web.config

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Full exception details:
I get an exception at the beginning of following class in \Models\IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41544592/861716

Answer (score 0):

this app.config it's from the project that start the application ? because it have to be on config file from the start up project too

Comment: this app.config is from the EF project,so you are saying the same changes shouldbe present in the startup project app.config too?

Comment: I udpated the web.config file aswell in the question that is part of startup

Comment: yes, because when the application starts, the config file use the config file from start project

Comment: I did it but still have the issue,do you have any pointers to debug or how t ofix this?

Comment: try run the command Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.9.9 to the web project, it will install all the required dll's and make the changes on your web.config file

Comment: do I have to uninstall any existing packages just to be sure?what would be the command to uninstall ,I just want to uninstall and install just to be safe...i tried replacing install with uninstall it throwed an error

Comment: Also I added more details on the exception, getting excpetion in class  `\Models\IdentityModels.cs`` ..I installed it but still get the exception in the same class

Comment: The first parameter on the context its the name of connection string on the web config file