# No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' . How to solve this error?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, odac

Summary: How to solve [**this error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzAmD.png) when generating database from model with Entity Framework and Oracle?

Details:
I tried researching and I realize there are similar questions here (like this one: [No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' - WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544592/no-entity-framework-provider-found-for-the-ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name) ) but my case seems to be different.

I'm new to Entity Framework and I'm making a custom destination component for a SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), an ETL tool. I am using a previously developed destination component as a template that used LINQ to SQL and was aimed at SQL Server. I decided to switch to Entity Framework since my component is for Oracle.

After various attempts installing and uninstalling, I managed to use ODAC and ODT for Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2017 community) according to this: https://community.oracle.com/message/14535771#14535771

When I tried to create an edmx file from my DB, I followed http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm#t8 , although it seems to use an older version. My wizard process looked like this:

[Model from DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yndbb.png). I'm not sure what's the real difference between Designer and Code First...

[Choose EF version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA53W.png). Although I did install the latest version of EF using NuGet, I get this message. I previously couldn't even generate the edmx because of an EF version error until I followed the instructions in the first link of this message.

After successfully generating the edmx model, after editing it, I tried to 
["Generate Database From Model..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9krR.png), but then I get [**this error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzAmD.png).

I'm pretty sure I registered to GAC when installing ODAC, though I'm not sure how to verify that. That might also be a problem since the ODAC installation wizard tells me to not do that when using NuGet, although I have to if I want to use ODT for Visual Studio properly AFAIK.

As I said, I'm new to EF, so I'm not sure how my App.config should look like, but currently it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>        
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
            <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <publisherPolicy apply="no" />
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.121.0.0 - 4.65535.65535.65535" newVersion="4.122.1.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
        <version number="*">
            <dataSources>
                <dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe))) " />
            </dataSources>
        </version>
    </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="GerenciadorExpurgoEF" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.GerenciadorExpurgoEF.csdl|res://*/Models.GerenciadorExpurgoEF.ssdl|res://*/Models.GerenciadorExpurgoEF.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=PurgeDB;PASSWORD=TESTUSR;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=TESTUSR&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was copying the App.config from my .NET Framework EF project into my .NET Core MVC project.
That, and as many other people have suggested on other questions, EF and the Oracle EF provider need to be installed in both projects (or at least referenced).